# Gzip Compression Format in Scala AWS Lambda code

Tags: scala, aws-lambda, compression, postman, gzip

I am using this method to compress my JSON response :

```
def compressString(content: String): Array[Byte] = {
 val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
 val gzs = new GZIPOutputStream(bos)
 gzs.write(content.getBytes("UTF-8"))
 gzs.close()
 val compressed = bos.toByteArray
 bos.close()
 compressed
}
```

So basically doing a myjson.toString() and using that as input for the above method to gzip it.
I put that compressed byte array into the response body:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "headers": {"Content-Encoding" : "gzip"},
  "body": "$compressed"
}
```

Hitting the lambda from aws console with a request I get the response with the byte array content int the body (array of integers):

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "headers": {
      "Content-Encoding": "gzip"
    },
  "body": [
        31,
       -117,
          8,
          ...
          ...
```

Using the same request in postman (with header Accept-Encoding gzip) I am getting error :

```
Error while processing content unencoding: incorrect header check
```

Now that makes me wonder **what format I have to use when putting the compressed response into the response body: byte-array? string? a file?**
Obviously the byte array does not work and Postman cannot uncompress the response body. Do I rather need to see compressed gibberish in the response so that Postman can uncompress it:

```
"\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0003�R�n�0\u0010��+�{�ZԲ,7m\u0012C�m�I\0���\b\u0002�\\EL%R W��ǿ��m 9� ....."
```

If yes, how do I produce the above compressed "gibberish" instead of the byte array of ints?

The end result should allow to query the data from Postman or similar tools and also programmatically uncompress the gzipped response with Scala on the client side.

Any advice welcome

Comment: you have any example website to try this usecase , that will be helpful

Comment: @PDHide any website that returns some kind of json response should work, I think

Comment: @i am not aware of anywebsite that returns a gzip please let me know if you find anything can try to help you out

Comment: well this is not really a website, but a Lambda which is written in Scala. AWS Lambdas have a response size limit and that is why I want to compress the response body

Comment: @PDHide this site can be used for example:
https://postman-echo.com/gzip

Comment: This doesn't return a compress response , its just a json

Comment: the URL is from Postman documentation:
'''This endpoint returns the response using gzip compression algoritm. The uncompressed response is a JSON string containing the details of the request sent by the client. For this endpoint to work, one should request with Accept-encoding header containing gzip as part of its value. Postman supports gzip, deflate and SDCH decoding and automatically sends them as part of the request.''' Check the headers of the response it says content-encoding is gzip, Postman auto-uncompresses it to json

Comment: The response header shows it a s gzip but postman uncompresses it shows it properly . I am not able to see this jibberish

Comment: the url is how it should work normally. I am trying to do the same. My lambda is supposed to return gzipped response body which Postman recognizes and automatically uncompresses. But as I described above, Postman cannot uncompress it ("incorrect header check"). So probably the body is not zipped correctly. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

can you try converting byte array to base64 before sending

```
let arrayBase64 = btoa([34,34....])

   ...
```

Pass the byte array as base64 of bytearray instead of passing byte array directly